# JMX с помощью рефлексии

Tags: java, рефлексия

Всем привет!

Есть несколько небольших проектов.
К одному из них прикрутил JMX. Получилось. Но теперь нужно сделать отдельный модуль, где JMX будет реализовано с помощью рефлексии.
Идея такова, что в классе, который нужно мониторить, у нужных методов\полей дописываются аннотации (напр. : @JMXTest) и по ним уже создаются все необходимые интерфейсы и классы для работы JMX.

Мне не очень понятен следующий момент: как с помощью рефлексии создать класс с необходимым набором полей и методов?
Как я понял, рефлексия позволяет создавать инстансы классов, но они должны быть описаны заранее.

Заранее благодарен за любую помощь и прошу не закидывать тухлыми овощами))

P.S.:Сама логика, реализованная в классах роли вроде бы не играет, так что код не прикладываю.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, это можно сделать с помощью Annotation Processors (примеры: [1](http://hannesdorfmann.com/annotation-processing/annotationprocessing101), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14302492/5661663))

Answer (score 1):

> Мне не очень понятен следующий момент: как с помощью рефлексии создать класс с необходимым набором полей и методов?

Никак. Рефлексия этого не позволяет. Тут скорее нужна кодогенерация в рантайме, она же программирование на лету.

---

В вашем же случае вам подойдет двухэтапная компиляция:

1. сначала компилируете программу;
2. потом (отдельной программой) генерируете нужные вам классы на основе атрибутов;
3. наконец компилируете эти сгенерированные классы компилятором java и добавляете к основной программе.

Comment: спасибо за помощь. Проблему удалось решить гораздо проще - с помощью интерфейса DynamicMBean, таким образом отпала необходимость кодогенерации.